# How to define step functions for weighted time interval with some undefined ends?

Tags: functions

Hourly salary for a part time job mostly depends on the time interval. If we work at night, for example, we get more money.

In our real life, we never care about the openness or closeness of the time interval as follows.

00:00 - 07:00 --> $20/hour

07:00 - 18:00 --> $15/hour

18:00 - 24:00 --> $17/hour

- If we checked-in at 06:59 and check-out at 07:00, we have worked for 1 minute at rate $20/hour.
- If we checked-in at 07:00 and check-out at 07:01, we have worked for 1 minute at rate $15/hour.
- The hourly payment at 07:00 is undefined.

## Questions

Each of the abscissa in the step function, as shown on the following figure for example, is mapped to exactly a single value of ordinate.

[image]

Therefore, how can we define the step function for the hourly payment mentioned above?

Comment: The function that you have defined will be dependent on two variables: the start time and  the finish time, isn't it? Hence you must have something like $f(x,y) = p(x-y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are entry and exit time, and $p$ is the hourly pay.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: I want to define the hourly payment in a step function.

Comment: That is, you want to define a function $hourlypayment : [0,24) \to \mathbb{N} \cup \infty$?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: Exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f : [0,24) \to \mathbb{N} \cup \infty$ by:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
20 \quad 0 < x < 7 \\
15 \quad 7 < x < 18 \\
17 \quad 18 < x < 24 \\
\infty \quad \text{otherwise }(x=0,7,18)
\end{cases}
$$

Now, to find the amount somebody working gets paid, all you do is integrate this function between the time he comes and the time he goes.For example, if he comes in at $5$ and goes at $19$, then you integrate :
$$
\displaystyle\int_5^{19} f(x)dx = (7-5)20 + (18-7)15 + (19-18)17 = 222
$$

Thus, you can design the function which will let you calculate your pay instantly.

Comment: Thanks. Just wait for a couple of hours to accept.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, the integration that is performed here is Lebesgue, because Riemann integrals must involve bounded functions, while this function is infinite at three points.